# how to convert float to decimal in swift

Tags: swift

In swift, how can I convert float value to decimal value and then add 2 variable? I have
`error: no exact matches in call to initializer`

```
let decimalValue: Decimal = 2.0
let floatValue: Float = 12.00
let sum = Decimal(floatValue) + decimalValue /// error: no exact matches in call to initializer

print(sum)
```

Comment: vadian has your answer, but just as a note: unless you have a specific reason that you need Float, [Double is preferred in Swift](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/thebasics#Floating-Point-Numbers). You'll run into a number of annoying little headaches like this when using Float, so make sure it's worth it. (The usual reasons are interacting with C APIs that require floats, or when you have massive arrays and memory concerns make it worth it.)

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decimal) reveals that there is no initializer which accepts a `Float`. There are only `init(_ value: Double)` and `init(floatLiteral value: Double)`

You have two reasonable options:

1. Declare `floatValue` implicit as `Double`

   ```
   let decimalValue: Decimal = 2.0
   let floatValue = 12.00 // <- inferred as Double
   let sum = Decimal(floatValue) + decimalValue
   ```
2. Call `init(_ value: Double)`

   ```
   let decimalValue: Decimal = 2.0
   let floatValue : Float = 12.00
   let sum = Decimal(Double(floatValue)) + decimalValue
   ```

Comment: Any suggestions of variable type should be used when working math operation?

Comment: `Decimal` provides all usual math operators, please read the documentation.

Comment: Decimal should be used when you need base-10 arithmetic. It is slower than binary encodings, and lacks some operations, so it is not a good first choice, but when you need base-10 floating point math it is the right solution. (If you can work in fixed-point math, for example when working with currencies, then Int is faster.) If you have very large vectors, then Float can be worth it to save space and improve usage of memory bandwidth (but computations may be faster or slower). Otherwise, and in most cases, use Double for floating point. It is the default for a reason.